# How to Sum a column from a JSON field in string format? DJANGO

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-3.0

How to Sum a column from a JSON field in string format? DJANGO

I have done it in several ways.

Could we help with this problem?

I am very grateful for everyone's attention. Thanks.

```
transaction = Transactions.objects.all().annotate(amount=KeyTransform('amount','metadata')).aggregate(Sum('amount'))
        print(totalAmount)
```

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: function sum(jsonb) does not exist
>
> APP | LINE 1: SELECT SUM("amount") FROM (SELECT("libertyblue_transaction"...
>
> APP | HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Perhaps the `amount` doesn't actually get casted to numerical value?

Comment: I get the "amount" as a string from a third-party API. And we store it in the database in a "metadata" column

Comment: `sum` on string will not gona work. Try to use type [cast](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#cast) - something like this: `Transactions.objects.all().annotate(str_amount=KeyTransform('amount','metadata')).annotate(amount=Cast('str_amount', output_field=FloatField())).aggregate(Sum('amount'))`

Comment: ProgrammingError: cannot cast type jsonb to double precision
APP | LINE 1: ..."libertyblue_transaction"."metadata" -> 'amount'))::double p...

Comment: Can you explain what your json field is exactly (show us an example) and what you're trying to sum?

Comment: column metadata : {'amount': "10.00"}